# This site requires a DHE-based SSL cipher suite. These are deprecated and will be removed in M52, around July 2016

Tags: apache, google-chrome, ssl, apache2

I've found this error in Chrome (Version 52.0.2743.82 (64-bit)) 
"This site requires a DHE-based SSL cipher suite. These are deprecated and will be removed in M52, around July 2016"

https://s13.postimg.org/5stng8o4n/login.png

The page could not be loaded in Chrome Canary (54.0.2835.0)

This is the error (but not the url)

https://s4.postimg.org/puwyrgfct/687474703a2f2f692e696d6775722e636f6d2f584c444c4c.png

My Apache web server is version 2.2.22 and SSL conf is the usual for that sites,

```
 SSLEngine On

 SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/mycerts/mycert.key
 SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/mycerts/mycert.crt
 SSLCACertificateFile /etc/ssl/mycerts/myca.crt
 SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
 SSLHonorCipherOrder on
 SSLCipherSuite "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA EECDH EDH+aRSA !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS"
```

It is not failing in Firefox, Safari or Opera. Neither in Chrome previously to Canary update.

Can somebody point me to the right direction to solve this SSL restriction for Chrome Canary?

Thanks

Comment: It's not exactly clear what you're asking.  Are you saying that Chrome Canary is having problems connecting to your site, giving you the error you posted?

Comment: What does "openssl ciphers" report for that string on the openssl used by your httpd?

Comment: @AndrewHenle bingo! just that. Any clues?

Comment: OK.  Can you post the output from `openssl s_client -connect server:port`? I suspect this might be a certificate issue.  IIRC it was around Chrome 41 that Google began to deprecate SHA-1 signed certificates.

Comment: New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
    Protocol  : TLSv1.2
    Cipher    : DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
(but the interesting migth be here)
    Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)
---

Comment: I'm just wondering if setting Cipher in Apache will resolve the issue

https://community.qualys.com/thread/11796

But Apache 2.2 has no ECDHE support, so maybe 
- a patch http://minaret.biz/tips/apache_dhparams.html
- an upgrade to 2.4 
will be a solution

Has anybody done something like that? Any solution on server side? Really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**. In apache2 virtual host, you must **aggregate** all these to **SSLCipherSuite**

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES128-GCM-SHA256:kEDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-DSS-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-DSS-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:AES:CAMELLIA:DES-CBC3-SHA:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!RC4:!MD5:!PSK:!aECDH:!EDH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA:!EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:!KRB5-DES-CBC3-SHA
```

Thank you all for your support! 
Hope it helps anybody in the same situation. Regards.